# Where can I store, read, and write data online using python?

Tags: python, json, database, csv

I wanted to make a python program that can read data online (could be JSON), and also capable of writing/updating that data. One of my option here is to use google spreadsheets API, but I also want to know if there are any other good alternatives (free or not).

I was planning to make an online a list of dictionaries that contain codes, and then the python program would then write that code as 'used' in the online data after being used.

I'm a beginner, so I don't know where to start from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use AWS or Firebase. All of them are easy to integrate into your code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one could be used too : https://jsonbin.io/